# Use WD MyCloud connected to Synology Diskstation?

Tags: nas, storage, synology, cloud

I had a 2tb WD MyCloud for a few years and recently upgraded to a Synology Diskstation with 4x4tb drives. I have migrated the data from my MyCloud to the DiskStation but seems silly to just let the MyCloud sit idle. Is there anyway to plug it into the Diskstation to utilize the storage on it?

Comment: well, I'd see if you can use the USB to plug the wd in as additional storage to the synology, but if you can't, just leave it on the network, and from the Synology, you can mount it as a folder within a share using the latest syno firmware, so you can add its storage to your array that way.

Comment: Great, I will have to look into that and try both methods. I am afraid since I am using RAID that it would cause backup issues just adding space after the initial setup?